# Creating TIN in standalone ArcPy script for ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst, arcgis-pro, contour, error-999999

I'm trying to create a TIN from contour data. My program will actually create an empty TIN, but it will still give me an error. Below is my code:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Aliza\Desktop\GIS Programming Fundamentals\Final_Project\Contours"
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
out_tin = "SampleTinssas"
height_field = "Elevation"
in_features = r"C:\Users\Aliza\Desktop\GIS Programming Fundamentals\Final_Project\Contours\Site_37_Contours.shp"
sr = arcpy.Describe(in_features).spatialReference
arcpy.CreateTin_3d(out_tin, sr, "Site_37_Contours.shp", "DELAUNAY")

arcpy.CheckInExtension("3D")
```

I know that the in_features portion of the tool is supposed to be in the form of a value table, but I have no clue how to format that. I know that my height needs to be included, but again, I have no idea where to start with that.

Below is my error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\python.exe" 
C:/Users/Aliza/PycharmProjects/finaltest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Aliza/PycharmProjects/finaltest.py", line 8, in <module>
    arcpy.CreateTin_3d(out_tin, sr, "Site_37_Contours.shp", "DELAUNAY")
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ddd.py", line 
 2922, in CreateTin
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\ddd.py", line 
2919, in CreateTin
    retval = 
convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.CreateTin_3d(*gp_fixargs((out_tin, 
spatial_reference, in_features, constrained_delaunay), True)))
  File "C:\Program 
Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 506, in 
<lambda>
   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (CreateTin).
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: I'm adding a tag for ArcGIS Pro because your error message indicates you are using that rather than ArcGIS Desktop 10.x.

Comment: The name of your TIN appears too long, it should be less than 13 characters but is precisely 13 characters... the *real* problem is that you have a **space in your path** which is a definite no-no for coverage data (coverage, TIN or GRID). Try making a folder c:\Try_this, make that your workspace and I'm fairly sure you'll find it works.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/47276370/820534

Answer (score 1):

There may be one or more of several things astray.

[@MichaelStimson's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262277/creating-tin-in-standalone-arcpy-script-for-arcgis-pro/262286#comment415737_262277) is definitely worth considering:

> The name of your TIN appears too long, it should be less than 13
>   characters but is precisely 13 characters... the *real* problem is
>   that you have a **space in your path** which is a definite no-no for
>   coverage data (coverage, TIN or GRID). Try making a folder
>   c:\Try_this, make that your workspace and I'm fairly sure you'll find
>   it works.

However, since you "know that the in_features portion of the tool is supposed to be in the form of a value table, but [you] have no clue how to format that", I think that you should first try running the tool from its tool dialog once, so that you can use the Geoprocessing | Results window to Copy As Python Snippet to get its correct syntax to paste into your script.